# What qualifies as a time series?

Tags: time-series, definition, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a simple question: does any data gathered over time could be treated as a time series? For instance, if I measure CPU load at certain intervals, would that be a time series? Actually, I'm not interested on actual time of the measurement. I could simply mark the points along x-axis as 1, 2, 3, ... -- what is relevant to me is certain values at certain points of time.

Further, could I do time series analysis on the data set if I have irregular observation intervals?

Comment: Yes to everything, by definition. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), [Search 1](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Time+series), [Search 2](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=time+series+unequal+intervals).

Comment: Also note that there are pros and cons to a time series because of the additional relationship of time: it gives you more information, but it also can tie things together in ways that can mislead you.

Comment: @Procrastinator, please visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15660/166924.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126791 (a later thread) for definitions of time series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a time series the same as a stochastic process?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126791/is-a-time-series-the-same-as-a-stochastic-process)

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Yes to everything, by definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series, https://www.google.com/search?q=Time+series, https://www.google.com/search?q=time+series+unequal+intervals. – user10525

Also note that there are pros and cons to a time series because of the additional relationship of time: it gives you more information, but it also can tie things together in ways that can mislead you. – Wayne