# Definition of random walk as a summation of independent random processes

Tags: central-limit-theorem, random-walk

I have a complete beginner question on random walk.
As per this [paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/srwbook.pdf)

```
Random walk – the stochastic process formed by successive summation of independent, identically distributed random variable....
```

I really cannot get past the first line. I thought that the central limit theorem and law of large numbers state that the mean of a large number of independent random processes will approximate a normal process. But the paper seems to indicate that the summation of these random processes is a random walk? So the mean is a normal process but the sum is a random walk? IS this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to know what a [stochastic process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919) is.**  In this context, it's just a collection of random variables $(X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots)$.

Seeing a simple worked example may help.  Let's set it up.  Suppose you have a collection of independent variables $\mathbf Y = (Y_0, Y_1, \ldots)$,  all with the same distribution.  For instance, each $Y_i$ could represent the flip of a fair coin using (say) $1$ for heads and $0$ for tails.  That's a stochastic process (which we could call a "Bernoulli process").

You can construct new processes out of old.  One way is to convert $\mathbf Y$ into its cumulative sum

$$\mathbf X = (Y_0, Y_0+Y_1, Y_0+Y_1+Y_2, \ldots)$$

This is a *random walk*.

---

**As an example,** let's consider a finite random walk of length $3$ based on fair coins.  That Bernoulli process $\mathbf Y$ has eight possible outcomes, aka "walks" or "paths," each with equal probabilities of $1/8$:

$$(0,0,0),\ (0,0,1),\  (0,1,0),\  (0,1,1),\  (1,0,0),\  (1,0,1),\  (1,1,0),\  (1,1,1).$$

The associated paths of $\mathbf X$, computed by taking cumulative sums, are therefore

$$(0,0,0),\ (0,0,1),\ (0,1,1),\ (0,1,2),\ (1,1,1),\ (1,1,2),\ (1,2,2),\ (1,2,3).$$

If you like, you can now identify the component variables $X_i$.  For instance, $X_0$ takes on the value $0$ four times, for a total probability of $4\times 1/8=1/2$, and the value $1$ four times, for a total probability of $1/2$.  $X_1$ takes on the values $0, 1,$ and $2$ with probabilities $1/4, 1/2, 1/4$, respectively.  And $X_2$ takes on the values $0,1,2,3$ with probabilities $1/8, 3/8, 3/8, 1/8$, respectively.  Notice that these three variables do *not* have identical distributions.  The distributions have different means and variances, too: their means are $1/2, 1, 3/2$ (in order) and their variances are $1/4, 1/2, 3/4$ (in order).

The component variables in a random walk also are *dependent.*  For instance, given that $X_1=0$ (which occurs only in the paths $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$), the chance that $X_2=0$ is $1/2$.  But given that $X_1=1$, the chance that $X_2=0$ is now zero: it's just not possible.  Because these conditional probabilities vary with the value of $X_1$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. In fact, no pair of these component variables is independent.

---

**The Central Limit Theorem** makes a statement about the distribution of $X_n$ when $n$ gets very large.  Besides assuming the $Y_i$ (out of which the $X_n$ are constructed) are independent and identically distributed, it has to assume that this common distribution has a finite variance.  The concept of a stochastic process is separate from any idea of limits (which wouldn't even make sense for a finite one, as in the example).  The CLT holds only for very special processes.

Answer (score 0):

Both are true.

Imagine I take $T$ steps, $x_t, t=1,...,T$ each normally distributed $x_t \sim N(0,1)$. Before we see any data, and for any $1<s<T$ we have $R_s = \sum_{t=1}^{s}x_t \sim N(0,s)$ - as you suspected.

However suppose we take a peek at the process at some point $s$ and happen to find that $R_s=100$. Then $R_{s+1} \sim N(100,1)$. That is, if we look at successive time steps, their values are linked because they share the same history.

The mean zero case only applies *before* we look at the data.

There are subtleties when the gap between time steps is reduced to the limit. When we can speak of the $x_t$ though these will generally be random variables not processes, it is $R_s$ which is the process.