# Detrending variance of event time-series

Tags: time-series, trend

I have time series of events. I observe that variance of inter-events intervals increases over the time.

**Is it possible to detrend my time series?**

## Update:

Example of data is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_M0k9qdY16ZbVdJM0NVYUJhdzQ). It is times when I observe event. Inter-events intervals are depicted below:

[image]

Just now I have the following solution:

1) I transform intervals($I$) to $log_{10}(I)$
2) Then I simply detrend $log_{10}(I)$

**Is it correct approach? Could you propose something more smart?**

Comment: It should be possible. Could you include a sample time series that would illustrate what kind of data you have?

Comment: Are you using the term "time series" [in its usual sense](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126791)?  It sounds like you might have a stochastic point process rather than a time series.

Comment: Some time series are a realisation of stochastic processes (of either kind)

Comment: It is from your link. I observe events during the time. LED blinking for example. It is stochastic processes. But as I understand I observe time series.

Comment: @RichardHardy I'he update post to answer Your question.