# I read that for a stationary process, Cov(Xt+h, Xt) should be a constant. What does it actually mean?

Tags: stationarity

According to wiki, covariance is a measure of the joint variability of two random variables.

Isnt Xt+h one particular value and Xt another value.. So what does it mean when you say covariance between these two values?﻿

Comment: In this context, $X_t$ is a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable). For example, $X_t$ may denote whether a coin flip lands heads or tails at time $t$. Or $X_t$ may denote the closing value of the S&P500 index on day $t$. Typically a random variable $X_t$ is defined so that the value of $X_t$ is known at time $t$.

Comment: What, if anything, do you understand by covariance? What you ciaim to have read _as per the title of your question_, is incorrect, and it would help if you would let us know what misconceptions you have about the notion of covariance.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126791.