# Time series models (e.g. ARMA) a type or extension of GLM? Particular/stipulated forms of dependence in time series models

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model, arima, glmm, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to understand the relationship between ARMA Time Series models and the GLM (Generalized Linear Model) family of models. As far I know, all GLMs have the following 3 components: 1) random component, 2) linear predictor, and 3) link function. Also, as far I know all GLMs are estimable by some flavor of Maximum Likelihood (e.g. "Conditional", "Partial").

Do ARMA Time Series models fall under the GLM family of models?

If so, please specify the random component, linear predictor, link function that qualify it to be a GLM and what sort of likelihood method is used to estimate it.

If not, please specify why it isn't in terms of the above 3 components and please comment on challenges of likelihood estimation, if relevant. Finally, if it borderline misses out on inclusion in the GLM family of models, why aren't ARMA models considered an extension of GLMs, the way GLMMs and GAMs are? Is it that much more of stretch from GLMs to ARMA models than from GLMs to GLMMs or from GLMs to GAMs?

Comment: Hi: ARMA models are a class of "time-series" models. GLM's, generally speaking, have nothing to do with time series. They are a different class of models that are more general ( sort of ) . GLM's are an extension of regression models where the response and it's distribution isn't required to be normally distributed. So, I wouldn't think of them as at all related.

Comment: Thank you, mlofton. Why do time series have nothing to do with GLMs? I formulated the question in terms of ARMA (a type of time series) so as to be able to be more specific, given the great variety of different type series models. I edited the title of question to broaden to all time series. GLMs include models that have a continuous predictor, which we assume to be normally distributed. Then why aren't time series GLMs? What exactly is it? Is it the lack of independence between observations? GLMMs also have non independent observations. Then why aren't Time Series an extension of GLMs?

Comment: Here is a link that, as I understand it, builds a bridge between time series and GLMs: http://www.math.umd.edu/~bnk/Ch_GLMsld.pdf I am still processing it.

Comment: One can use GLMs for time series analysis.  However, ARMA models formulate a very particular way in which observations may be related: in particular, they involve *additive* terms that are unsuited for (and cannot even be accommodated by) most GLMs.  Where people have been successful in combining the approaches they have supposed there is some underlying ARMA (or ARIMA or whatever) model for an *unobserved* process that describes the GLM link function.  As such, neither ARMA nor GLM can be viewed as "extensions" of each other, but both offer useful techniques that can be combined.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you. Am I to conclude that a time series is not a type of GLM because the observations are not independent? A time series is not an extension of GLM because unlike in GLMM, where some generic/unspecified dependence among observations within a cluster is allowed for, in a time series, we stipulate the precise way in which observations are correlated? And while we can describe the random component, linear predictor, and link function in a time series, it is the stipulation of the exact way in which observations are dependent that place time series in a category of their own?

Comment: What forms of dependence between observations can a GLM/GLMM handle? What is it about the "additivity of observations" in ARMA that the GLM/GLMM cannot deal with? I would appreciate someone enlightening me with regards to these questions. Thank you.

Comment: A [time series is a type of stochastic process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919) whereas a GLM is a regression model.  As I mentioned previously, one can combine techniques from both.  Debating whether that might allow you to view one as an "extension" of the other seems without much value either for understanding or in practice.

Comment: ColorStatistics: I'm honestly at a loss for how to explain it but they are pretty unrelated. GLMs ( I'm not familar with GLMM's ) assume that the response is based on the predictors ( exogenous ) in some parametric way. ARIMA models only have two kind of predictors: the previous values of the series and error terms. I imagine that there must be those who somehow use GLM's for time series prediction but this was not the original intention of Mcullogh and Nelder.

Comment: I woud read Box and Jenkins for the original explanation of ARIMA models and Mcullogh and Nelder or Fox for GLMs. Note that GLM's, as far as I know, do not assume that observations can be correlated. This makes it difficult to use them for time series.

Comment: ColorStatistics: I just looked at Kedem link. I should not say that GLMS cannot be used for time-series models. Even regression models can be used for time series if the predictors are time subscripted. I'm just saying that to think of the two classes of models as in any way related, would, IMHO, be a mistake because they are so different. But, yes, under certain assumptions, GLMs can be used for TS models. But so can say random forests and I would not think of them as being  related to ARIMA  or GLMs. My advice is to not try to relate these things and just understand them on their own.

Comment: Thank you for those references, mlofton. I'll look them up to get some more clarity. I started with the question in my mind of why time series analysis is taught separately from panel data analysis. Most panel methods can be unified under the GLM umbrella. I was wondering why time series methods do not fit under the same umbrella. I still don't get it.

Comment: @mlofton, I think it would be enlightening to understand the relation between GLMs and ARMA. Additionally, I think one could start from comparing a simple linear model to ARMA since ARMA is linear in parameters. It looks just like a linear model save for the fact that some of the regressors are unobservable lags of error terms. ColorStatistics, on a somewhat tangential note, see my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model) on what a regression model is and whether ARMA is a special case of it.

Comment: HI Richard: If you can provide a relation, I would definitely like to read about it. I agree that they are both linear ( well, glm's are transformed to linear ) but besides linear and the fact that they can both predict, given coefficient estimates, I don't see much else. Looking forward to some interesting connections that I don't see.

Comment: @ColorStatistics: It really depends on your preferences as far as references.   There are so many texts that cover arima.  I'm not a big fan of box-jenkins. In a way, chatfield's somewhat new "green" text gives the "bigger picture" in time series which, while not so technical and not specifcally geared to arima ( it does cover it but it covers other classes too ) is a good read IMHO. For GLM's, mcullagh and nelder is pretty dense.  I would check out john fox's text which doesn't get enough love IMHO. Everyone is so different , so there's always bias when  recommending.  Others may have recs ?

Comment: @richard hardy: Just one other thing which you probably know anyway.  note that the AR terms in a univariate ARIMA model are all lagged versions of themselves, so the estimation procedure is totally different from a linear model.  Hamilton has a short discussion on how estimating an AR as a linear regression model can be problematic.

Comment: ColorStatistics,  I'm not your advisor but it's best to stick to simple time-series ARIMA type models versus GLM's for now. Panel data is a  different animal that is kind of a different topic in time-series ( from arima ) and MUCH MORE COMPLEX, atleast to me. Trying to look at all these different things  at one time will really make your head spin. Leep in mind that,  looking at econometric time series analysis versus arima type time series analysis ( which kind of don't fall under the econometric category )  can be a total adventure in itself. Structural versus reduced is key difference.

Comment: @mlofton, I believe one of the most popular, or perhaps the most popular approach for estimating AR models is by OLS applied on an appropriately constructed design matrix containing lags of the dependent variable. So this is basically the same as a linear regression. The only mechanical difference is in the construction of the design matrix where $p+1$ windows of length $n-p$ of the original $n$-long time series are used for constructing $y$ and $X$. There are some differences in finite sample properties but the asymptotic results are about the same in both AR and cross-sectional regression.

Comment: @mlofton, I am honestly interested in the question (so I am not picking on you) and would have written an answer if I had one ready (or had enough time to sit down and think about it properly). I am looking forward to someone doing that instead of me.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Hi.: My apologies if I sounded like you were picking on me. I just don't know how to relate them so I think it's best for someone else to explain. I think it's true that GLMs can be used for time-series but that still doesn't mean any real relation between  the two classes of models, that I know of.  well, glm is parametric and linear. ARIMA is kind of non-parametric and linear. they both can be used for prediction. definitely I agree though that variations of standard GLM class can be used for time-series as OP mentioned initially. I said no initially which was incorrect.

Comment: @RichardHardy: You may be correct about the estimation algorithm of OLS being used and it not making much of a difference asymptotically. I'll have to look at Hamilton again to update my memory. The predictors are lagged so I think there is a violation of OLS in terms of orhogonality of residual and predictor but I can't remember at the moment clearly. There are somewhat complex algorithms that have been developed for estimation of ARIMA models so I have a feeling it matters. Note that there are also constraints on AR coefficient values  due to invertibility constraint..

Comment: @ColorStatistics: This weekend I will look for two papers ( I have somewhere ) that you may be interested in reading. They are not DIRECTLY related to GLM's or ARIMA models but more about error-terms and the historical background regarding models etc. They will provide some background which may be helpful. All of this time-series material is complex due to the fact that time-series is an interdisciplinary field so used in statistics, econometrics, dsp etc. each field has own terminology and assumptions and framework which makes the topic tricky.

Comment: @ColorStatistics: Here is a link to one of the papers I was refererring to.. http://fitelson.org/woodward/haavelmo.pdf. I have a hardcopy of the other one ( which in some ways is more useful ) but  I can't find it on the net. The paper link is here but currently no access. https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/econometric-theory/article/error-term-in-the-history-of-time-series-econometrics/EF8D70292202877EB9DDC5CE6F3D4FE6. if you want it, my email has a 2 after the name and server is the company with a g. all the best and interesting question for sure.

Comment: @mlofton, The violation of orthogonality you mention is the reason for the difference in finite sample properties of OLS for a linear model vs. "OLS" (more precisely, conditional LS) for AR. For ARMA models, the estimation algorithm indeed differs considerably because there are unobservable variables in the model that can not be handled by OLS. It is interesting in which sense you mean ARMA to be nonparametric; I cannot recall this kind of statement about ARMA from before, but that does not mean it is wrong. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RichardHardy. Nice explanation of estimation difference. As far as ARIMA being "non-parametric", I probably shouldn't have used that terminology.  What I really mean is that the error term is generally normally distributed so different from the GLM where the response has an underlying  not-necessarily normal distribution. My mistake for confusing terminology and thanks for clarification.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I looked at Harvey's "The Econometric Analysis of Time Series" which provides beautiful discussions ( a bit terse but good ) of the computations involved in estimating time-series models. For the AR(1) or AR(p), I agree with you that OLS is asymptotically equivalent to an ML procedure. But, for anything more complicated where the error is not N(0,$\sigma^2$), I strongly recommend Harvey's text for a detailed and clear explanation. Mentioning this only because I don't want future thread readers to think that that the OLS alternative is always a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @mlofton, I think there is no material difference between the treatment of normal and other distributions in AR vs. regression models: OLS is often used regardless of the distribution and is suboptimal from the perspective of likelihood maximization unless the true distribution is normal; in the latter case, OLS and maximum likelihood estimators of model coefficients coincide. For ARMA models with nonempty MA part, OLS is of course inapplicable. (By the way, I did not say that OLS is asymptotically equivalent to ML, even if that is correct.)

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Like I said,  Andrew Harvey basically has a whole text devoted to the numerical estimation of regression "type" time-series models. He's  well respected in the field of econometric time-series and the book is quite good so I recommend checking it out for a better explanation than I can give. The nature of the error terms ( AR(1), MA(1), white noise ) matters a lot.

Comment: @mlofton, Thanks! I will give it a try. Unfortunately, my list of papers and books to read grows considerably faster than I am checking off items in it...

Comment: @Richard Hardy. I have the same problem. But I highly recommend that it gets pushed up on your list. I find Andrew Harvey to be incredibly terse in his writing style. ( he's written 3 books in total and each has merits. each is unique ). But if I view one of  his pages as a chapter,  then, in the end, particularly in the case of "econometric analysis of time series", it's really worth it. It's a very unique book in terms of the issues it deals with from a computational persective. No pseudo-code unfortunately but still great if enough time spent on it. All the best.

Comment: @mlofton, thanks, I will pay extra attention to Harvey then!

Comment: @Richard Hardy: He's definitely the man when it comes to computational algorithms in time-series type regression models. or even just time-series models in general. All of his books are recommended but, for time-series regresssion, the one I mentioned in above is the most relevant.

Comment: @mlofton : Some of your comments should be posted as answers, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.  In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not rely on reading comments for essential information.

Comment: @whuber : Some of the comments on this question should be posted as answers, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.  In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not rely on reading comments for essential information.

Comment: @Peter O. Okay. Thanks. I  will keep that in mind. The problem a lot of times is that my comment is of the "look at X here which will help to understand Y" type which is don't think is an answer. ( but it's too long to go into details that would totally explain it ). But I'll try harder in the future.