# Is a generalized linear model (GLM) an appropriate model where ARCH effects are found in the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, garch

The dependent and independent variables are all time series variables. The dependent variable is found to have ARCH effects. Is a GLM an appropriate model for modeling the relationship between the dependent and independent variables?

Answer (score 0):

A GLM will not account for the ARCH effects, if that is what you are interested in. If the domain of your dependent variable is the real line, use some form of GARCH to account for conditional heteroskedasticity. GLMs are useful when the domain of the dependent variable is not the real line but e.g. $\{0,1\}$ or $(0,\infty)$ or something else.

Comment: See also the answer in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553072/do-time-series-models-fall-under-glm).

Comment: Thqnks for the response, Richard Hardy. The paper is actually tries to model GDP as a function of some public debt variables. The author  however cites the existence of ARCH effects in the GDP variable as a reason for the use of GLM.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Richard Hardy. The paper I came across actually tries to model GDP as a function of some public debt variables. The author  however cites the existence of ARCH effects in the GDP variable as a reason for the use of GLM. This is what I am not sure is correct as I have not come across any other sources that depict the GLM as a suitable model in the presence of ARCH effects in a dependent variable.

Comment: @Topsy, hmm, that does not quite sound reasonable, but perhaps the authors gives some good reasons?

Comment: thanks again. The authors only write that, the data properties shows that the sum of the ARCH and GARH coefficient with the value 0.523838 is close to one indicating a unitary property that required application of GLM in the relationship between the regressors and the regressand. I am not sure if they should not have been using generalised least squares instead of GLM

Comment: @Topsy, from the current standpoint, I would use neither GLM (a model that can be estimated using various estimation techniques) nor GLS (an estimation technique that does not fully determine what the model is) but estimate an appropriate GARCH model using maximum likelihood (the standard estimation technique for GARCH-type models).

Comment: thank you for the responses.