# How to know which one is random variable?

Tags: time-series, expected-value

Given a time series equation:$$x_t=\beta_1+\beta_2t+w_t$$
where $w_t$ is white noise.

When I am calulateing the mean:$$E[x_t]=E[\beta_1+\beta_2t+w_t]$$
$$=\beta_1+\beta_2t+E[w_t]$$
$$=\beta_1+\beta_2t$$

However, isn't the varibale $t$, also a random variable s.t. the answer should be $$E[x_t]=\beta_1+\beta_2E[t]$$?

Edit: the whole question is:

Consider the time series $x_t=\beta_1+\beta_2t+w_t$, where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are known constants and $w_t$ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Is $t$ *random*, or is it a deterministic sequence?

Comment: @Alexis edited.

Comment: @Tim that's interesting

Comment: @Tim It's hard to see how modeling the time in a time series as a random variable would accomplish anything.  Given that when one calls data a "time series" it means [there is an equal interval between successive times,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919) the only freedom left to introduce randomness lies in the start time and the common interval. I suspect extremely few people have ever seen an application where it was useful to model the start or the interval as a random variable.

Comment: @whuber I missed it's time...