# Can two weak stationary time series $X_t, Y_t$ have covariance $\mathrm{Cov}(X_t,Y_t)$ that changes over time?

Tags: self-study, covariance, stationarity

Can two weak stationary time series $X_t, Y_t$  have covariance $Cov(X_t,Y_t)$ that changes over time? No solution is needed, please give me some hints. I think it can but I find it is difficult to support my idea.

Comment: If you cannot prove your idea, just sharing your idea is also good. I think Cov(Xt, Yt) may change over time. But I can not find the way to support my idea.

Comment: Is that a homework exercise? If so, please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its [Wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It a question that teacher left us, not a necessary homework. Thanks your comment !

Comment: Hint: let each series consist of *iid* variables.  Does this imply the variables in one series must be independent of those in the other?

Comment: Thanks your hint. Yes! It must be independent. But because of independence, the covariance must be 0 which will not change with t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X_t),$ with "times" $t=0,1,2,\ldots,$ be variables with independent and identical distributions having finite variance $\sigma^2$ -- which implies they form a stationary (whence weakly stationary) [stochastic process.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919)  Suppose further that this common distribution is [symmetric about $0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28992): this means the $-X_t$ all have the same distribution as the $X_t.$  For instance, the standard Normal distribution is symmetric about $0.$

Define

$$Y_t = (-1)^t X_t$$

and notice that

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_t,Y_t) = \operatorname{Cov}(X_t,(-1)^tX_t) = (-1)^t \operatorname{Cov}(X_t,X_t) = (-1)^t\sigma^2$$

alternates between $\sigma^2$ and $-\sigma^2:$ that is, it changes over time.  Nevertheless, the symmetry of the distribution implies the $(Y_t)$ are identically distributed and, since the $(X_t)$ are independent, the $(Y_t)$ are independent too.  Thus $(Y_t)$ is a (weakly) stationary process, too.  *In this example the covariance changes over time.*

Comment: Thanks!!! This is really ingenious!