# Why is this linear combination of random variables from a white noise stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

I'm looking at the following definition of a *causal* AR(p) (autoregressive) model:

> An AR(P) model $\phi(B)x_t= \epsilon_t$ is said to be causal if it has a **stationary** solution
> $$x_t=\epsilon_t +\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}b_i\epsilon_{t-i}$$
> where the $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|{b_i}|<\infty$ and $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is a white noise process.

How do we know that this solution is stationary?

Comment: Apply the definition.  I provide examples of that at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/566582/919.  My answer there doesn't directly address your problem, because this is an infinite linear combination, but the ideas are the same.

Comment: Hi: In time series terninology ( but not in engineering or mathematics in general ), a white noise RV is synonymous with an N(0,1) RV and an infinite linear combination of standardized normal random variables is known to be stationary. A proof of the latter is beyond the scope of this comment but I would think that it might be in say Brockwell and Davis.

Answer (score 2):

There are technical issues associated with the infinite sum.  Identifying and resolving them requires some attention to the definitions, so let's begin there.

- A *white noise process* $\epsilon_t$ (in discrete time indexed by the integers) when (a) its mean $E[\epsilon_t]=0$ for all $t$ and (b) its autocorrelation function $$R_\epsilon(h,t)=E[\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t+h}]$$ is finite for all integral $h$ and zero when $h\ne 0.$  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Discrete-time_white_noise.  Accordingly, we may drop references to $t$ in the notation for the autocorrelation.
- A *stationary process* $X_t$ is one for which given any dimension $n\ge 1$ and any vector $(h_1,\ldots, h_n)$ of integers, the joint distribution of $(X_{t+h_1}, X_{t+h_2}, \ldots, X_{t+h_n})$ does not vary with $t.$  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition.

  (There are weaker definitions of stationarity.  You will have no trouble establishing the result for any of them by emulating the argument used here for this *strong stationarity* condition.)
- A countable linear combination of random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$ given by coefficients $b_0, b_1, b_2, \ldots$ is the limit (if it exists) of the finite partial sums, $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i X_i = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i X_i.\tag{*}$$

But limit in what sense?  The strictest sense is the pointwise limit of the random variables; but the one most germane to models is the limit in distribution.  It doesn't matter which definition we adopt, as you will soon see.

---

First notice that the definition of a white noise process is so general that it doesn't even guarantee a white noise process is stationary!  *When we begin with a non-stationary process $\epsilon_t,$ the stated result will generally be false.*  As a counterexample, let $b_i=0$ for all $i:$ it asserts $\epsilon_t + \sum b_i \epsilon_{t-i} = \epsilon_t$ is stationary, flatly contradicting the assumption.

To make any progress, then, *we must assume that $\epsilon_t$ is a* stationary *white noise process.*

With this assumption, the derivation I gave at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/566582/919 shows that *any finite linear combination* of a stationary process is stationary.  Applying this result to the situation in the question with the coefficients $(1, b_1, \ldots, b_{n})$ shows

> The process $X^{(n)}_t = \epsilon_t + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \epsilon_{t-i}$ is stationary for $n=1, 2, \ldots.$

Thus, *every partial sum on the right hand side of $(*)$ is a stationary process.*

**We need to show the limit of a sequence of stationary processes is itself stationary.**  But this is trivial: the definition of stationarity means all finite $n$-variate marginal distributions are unchanged by time translation, so upon taking limits we deduce all finite $n$-variate marginal distributions of the limit are unchanged, whence (by definition of stationarity) the limiting process is stationary.  Applying this to the sequence $n\to X^{(n)}$ of processes implies

$$X_t = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_t^{(n)} = \epsilon_t + \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i \epsilon_{t-i}$$

is stationary, *QED.*