# Integral of Bernoulli Process

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes

I have a stochastic process $X_{t}$ that has probability $p(t)$ that $a < X_{t} < b$ with $p(t)$ a decreasing function.  I want to find the random variable $D_{t}$ which describes the duration $X_{t}$ has been within $a$ and $b$ up until $t$. Let $Y_{t} \sim$ Bernoulli($p(t)$) denote whether $X_{t}$ is in the interval then $D_{t}$ can be given by:
$$D_{t} = \int_0^t Y_{u} \ du$$

Is there any way I can recover the PDF or CDF of $D_{t}$? I've tried by taking the limit of the [Poisson-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) distribution/infinite convolutions but haven't had any luck. My intuition tells me that
$$\mathbb{E}[D_{t}] = \int_0^t p(u) \ du$$
but I'd really like to have the PDF/CDF.

#### Update:

Thanks to comments, I realize I need to add additional information:

I also have that the joint density for two points in time $t_{1} > t_{0}$ is given by
$$f_{X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{0}}}(x_{t_{1}},x_{t_{0}}) = f_{X_{t_{1}-t_{0}}}(x_{t_{1}}-x_{t_{0}}) \cdot f_{X_{t_{0}}}(x_{t_{0}})$$
and more generally the joint density for $n$ points in time is
$$f_{X_{t_{n-1}},\dots,X_{t_{0}}}(x_{t_{n-1}},\dots,x_{t_{0}}) = f_{X_{t_{0}}}(x_{t_{0}})\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_{X_{t_{i}-t_{i-1}}}(x_{t_{i}}-x_{t_{i-1}})$$

Comment: Recover the PDF from what information?  Surely the PDF must depend on the properties of the process $(X_t),$ about which you state almost nothing aside from the decreasing property of $p.$

Comment: @whuber I know $p$, and since I could write $D$ as function of "known" random variables I figured I should be able to "know" $D$. This could very well not be the case but I don't know what else would be needed

Comment: What you lack is information about full distribution of the process: $p$ gives you relevant information only about the marginal distributions.

Comment: @whuber Could you be more specific on "information about full distribution"? I know the the PDF and CDF of $X$ for any $t$ (which is how I know $p$), I just didn't include that in my question since I didn't see how that would be used. Is this what you mean? If so, I can add that to the question.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160733/919 for some useful definitions and characterizations of stochastic processes.  To determine $D_t,$ you need information on the *joint* distributions of the various $X_t$ and $X_s.$

Comment: @whuber I think I see what you are saying. The conditional density $f_{X_{t}|X_{s}}$ is equal to the density of $X_{t}-X_{s}$ for $t>s$. So the joint density should be $f_{X_{t-s}} \cdot f_{X_{s}}$. I'm not sure if this is enough, but I can add this to my question if that is beneficial.

Comment: That kind of information is *crucial.*  Without it, your problem has no definite solution.  Note that to fully define any stochastic process, you need more than just the marginals or the bivariate joint densities: you need *all* the finite-dimensional joint densities.

Comment: @whuber By all finite-dimensional joint densities do you mean all $f_{X_{0},X_{1},\dots,X_{n}}$ where $X_{i}$ is short hand for $X_{t_{0}}$ for any $n$?

Comment: Yes: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/566582/919.