# Transform ARIMA(2,1,0) into MA infinity process

Tags: time-series, arima, moving-average

How do I transform ARIMA(2,1,0) into MA infinity process? I tried to compute it as

$$y_t=\frac{1}{(1-\phi_1 B-\phi_2 B^2)(1-B)}\epsilon_t$$

But then I cannot find a way to separate this denominator...

Comment: An ARIMA(2,1,0) process is not stationary so it can't be represented as MA$(\infty)$.

Comment: Then how to compute the variance?

Comment: Which variance?

Comment: variance of $y_t$

Comment: or similarly, forecast error of $y_t$

Answer (score 1):

In this (conventional) notation, $\mathcal E = (\epsilon_t)$ is a sequence of random variables indexed by integers ("times") $t=\ldots -2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots.$ Such sequences are known as [time series processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919).

#### Mathematical preliminaries

This section emphasizes the way in which familiar algebraic methods apply directly, without any appreciable change, to expressions involving the backshift operator $B.$

Time series processes (defined on a common sample space) can be added term by term and multiplied by scalars (real or complex numbers) term by term.  These operations satisfy the [vector space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Notation_and_definition).  Let $\mathbb T$ be such a vector space.

The *lag* or ["backshift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator) operator $B$ shifts a time series process $\mathcal X = (X_t)$ forward one step in time:  that is,

$$(B\mathcal X)_t = X_{t-1}.$$

The set of linear operators $A:\mathbb T \to \mathbb T$ forms an *algebra* because any two such operators can be multiplied *via* composition (applying one to the result of the other).  This algebra has a *unit,* written "$\mathbf 1,$" which is the identity map: it sends every time series process to itself.

Any operator, like $B,$ generates a subalgebra of linear operators formed by linear combinations of $B$ and $1.$  Letting $\mathcal R$ be the scalars (real or complex numbers), this subalgebra consists of expressions of the form

$$a_0 \mathbf 1 + a_1 B + a_2 B^2 + \cdots a_n B^n$$

where the $a_i\in\mathcal R$ are scalars.  Such a linear combination acts on time series process in the obvious way; namely,

$$((a_0 \mathbf 1 + a_1 B + a_2 B^2 + \cdots a_n B^n)\mathcal X)_t = a_0 X_t + a_1 (B\mathcal X)_t + \cdots + a_n (B^n\mathcal X)_t.$$

In the special case of the lag operator $B$ this has the especially simple and relevant form

$$((a_0 \mathbf 1 + a_1 B + a_2 B^2 + \cdots a_n B^n)\mathcal X)_t = a_0 X_t + a_1 X_{t-1} + \cdots + a_n X_{t-n}.$$

The question concerns *inverting* such operators.  In particular, it concerns the inverse of

$$P(B)=(\mathbf1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2)(\mathbf1+B) = \mathbf1 + (1-\phi_1)B - (\phi_1+\phi_2)B^2 - \phi_2B^3$$

where $\phi_i\in\mathcal R$ are fixed scalars.

#### Inverting the operator $P(B).$

**Ordinarily, such operators are not evidently invertible:** and that is the crux of the question.  There are two ways to proceed.  Both rely on making sense of *infinite sums* of such operators, thereby enlarging the algebra generated by $B.$

Rather than get involved in the analytical niceties of this, I propose to skip all such issues for the moment and merely work *formally* with infinite power sums, pretending that they always converge.  (There is a sense in which they do; it relies on defining an [ultrametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) in which higher powers of $B$ grow smaller.)

When this is the case, *familiar algebraic techniques apply.*  In particular,

1. **We can factor polynomials** in $B,$ provided we allow for Complex roots.  That is,

   $$\mathbf 1 -\phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 = (\mathbf 1 -\lambda_1 B)(\mathbf 1 - \lambda_2 B)$$ where, upon expanding the right hand side, we see

   > $$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \phi_1;\quad \lambda_1\lambda_2 = -\phi_2.$$

   You find the $\lambda_i$ in the same way you would solve any such polynomial equations.
2. **We can perform a [partial fractions decomposition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)**   This is how you "separate" the denominator.  In particular, when the $\lambda_i$ are distinct and neither equals $-1,$ then

   > $$\frac{1}{(1 - \lambda_1 x)(1-\lambda_2x)(1+x)} = \frac{A_1}{1 - \lambda_1 x} + \frac{A_2}{1 - \lambda_2 x} + \frac{A_0}{1+x}$$

   where the $A_i$ are *numbers* that are readily computed in terms of the $\lambda_i.$  Formally, *the same result holds for any polynomial in $B,$* because all the rules of algebra are the same.

   (One easy way to find the $A_i$ is illustrated by computing $A_0:$ multiply both sides by $1+x$ and take the limit as $x\to -1.$  The right hand side reduces to $A_0$ while the left hand side is the limit of $1/((1-\lambda_1 x)(1-\lambda_2 x)),$ obtained simply by plugging $x=-1$ in (because this fraction is a continuous function of $x$ at $-1$), giving $$A_0 = \frac{1}{(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)}.$$  The other $A_i$ are found the same way.  When there are repeated roots the work is a little more involved but leads to similar results.)
3. Thus, **inversion of the original operator** $(1-\phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2)(1+B)$ is (formally) reduced to the problem of inverting simple expressions of the form $1 - \lambda_i B.$  [Newton's (generalized) Binomial Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) tells us what the inverse must be (if it is to exist at all), because for any $\lambda\ne 0,$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\mathbf 1-\lambda B} &= (\mathbf1 + (-\lambda)B)^{-1} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{-1}{j}(-\lambda)^j\,B^j \\
&= \mathbf 1 + \lambda B + \lambda^2 B^2 + \cdots + \lambda^j B^j + \cdots
\end{aligned}$$

(You ought to recognize this expression as the sum of a [geometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html); the common ratio is $\lambda B.$)

**Combining results $(2)$ and $(3)$** tells us the inverse of $P(B)$ is a sum of powers of $B$ where the coefficient of the $j^\text{th}$ power is given by the partial fraction coefficients $A_i$ and roots $\lambda_i$ as

> $$\frac{1}{P(B)} = \mathbf 1 + \cdots + \left[A_0 (-1)^j + A_1 \lambda_1^j + A_2 \lambda_2^j\right]B^j + \cdots \tag{*}$$

Generally (and still formally), this is the so-called "$\operatorname{MA}(\infty)$" expansion of $1/P(B).$  It will be applied to the time series process $(\epsilon_t)$ to produce an explicit "infinite moving average" expression for each $Y_t$ in terms of $\epsilon_t, $ $\epsilon_{t-1},$ and so on.

---

When considerations of stationarity (essentially, convergence of infinite sums) come up, we can dodge that issue by expressing $(1-B)\mathcal Y$ (the "first difference" of $\mathcal Y$) as an $MA$ process using these same techniques, because

$$(1-B)\mathcal Y  = \left((\mathbf 1 - \lambda_1B)(\mathbf 1 - \lambda_2 B)\right)^{-1}\mathcal E.$$

When we expand the right hand side, what makes the resulting infinite sequences converge analytically (not just formally) is the assumption that $|\lambda_i|\lt 1,$ thereby causing the terms $\lambda_i^j$ in $(*)$ to shrink to zero rapidly as $j$ grows.  Assuming $B$ is a *bounded operator* (according to some useful metric on $\mathbb T$), this will assure convergence in that metric.

Comment: Thank you so much. So regarding your last method I(1), how do we compute the variance of $y_t$ (the variance of process ARIMA(2,1,0))

Comment: It depends on what you assume about $(\epsilon_t).$ Most of the time one makes assumptions that imply $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$ is a constant regardless of $t$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_s)=0$ when $t\ne s.$ This is enough to apply the basic rules of working with covariances to *finite* linear combinations of the $\epsilon_t;$ you then have to take limits.

Comment: I mean, is it possible to calculate variance of ar(2) first, then use this result in arima(2,1,0)?
If yes, how?
Thanks.