# Stationarity - Model vs Time-series

Tags: time-series, model, stationarity, autoregressive

What is the difference, if there are any, between checking for stationarity in a time series and then in a model (for example an AR model), which is built on that data. I recently encountered that problem reading some literature, where they double checked it, which was quite confusing for me. Can a model be stationary if the time series is not and vice versa? Or does the stationarity of the model imply such for the time-series?

Comment: Hi: The ( weak or strong ) stationarity of a time series is independent of the model for it. Weak means that the mean and variance are constant over the series. Strong means weak + the covariances are time invariant. So,the requirements  in both cases are model independent. It's not clear to me why they would check twice ?

Comment: Your sense of the word "time series" is that of *a single realization of a time series process* (that is, the "model").  It doesn't have a joint distribution and "stationary" does not apply.  Only the *model* can be stationary.  The realization, though, can supply evidence concerning the plausibility of a stationary model: that's the meaning of "checking for stationarity."  Read the James Hamilton quotations at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126830/919 for more about the realization/process distinction.

Comment: Thank both of you, it seemed that I didnt quite understood the definition of Stationarity and how to check for it.